# Which CSS selectors to use to pull numbers from a webpage using .select() in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the current stock price from a webpage using python. I am having trouble using Beautiful Soup to pull the numbers. I don't know what CSS selector to use. I've tried combinations of span, div, tr, tbody, td. Attached is a picture of the HTML. Note that the number I am after is 368.45:

HTML:

[image: HTML]

Here is the essence of my python3 code (I am using Ubuntu in case that matters):

```
res = requests.get(#webpage_url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
stock_price = soup.select(#what CSS selector do I use?)
print(stock_price[0].getText())
```

I am basically just asking how do I use the `.select()` method to get the highlighted text in the attached HTML snapshot.

Comment: Did you try searching for the "posquote" table cells and then reading the contents of the span within?

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching the cell with the `posquote` class that contains the span and get the string from there

`stock_price = soup.find('td', class_='posquote').string`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Do you know a good way for me to learn beautiful soup/CSS selectors inside and out? I am reading "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python," but in that book they don't go in depth enough into beautiful soup/HTML/CSS.

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get the wrong result or an error? As for learning BeautifulSoup, I think the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is pretty straightforward.